# writing a function queue in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have an object which can only place 60 API calls per minute. So what I would like to do, is when a function call comes that I know I wont be allowed to place, add it to a queue, and call the function again at a more convenient time.

Heres how I thought to fix it

```
var API_caller = function(){
    this.function_queue = [];
};

API_caller.prototype.make_api_call = function(){
    if(this.can_make_call()){
        this.make_call();
    } else {
        // If I cant place an API call then add 
        // the function to the function queue
        this.function_queue.push(this.make_api_call);       
    }
};

API_caller.prototype.queue_call = function(){
    // remove function from queue and call it
    var func = this.function_queue.shift();
    func();
}
```

This works fine for functions without parameters but what if `make_api_call()` had a parameter

```
API_caller.prototype.make_api_call = function(data){
    if(this.can_make_call()){
        this.make_call();
    } else {
        // If I cant place an API call then add 
        // the function to the function queue
        this.function_queue.push(this.make_api_call(data));     
    }
};
```

In this case however, `make_api_call(data)` will be evaluated before it is pushed to `function_queue` and `func` will no longer hold a function causing `queue_call()` to error.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partially apply arguments to a function with `bind`:

```
this.function_queue.push(this.make_api_call.bind(this, data));
```

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for support in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The queue entry should contain the function, `f` and the parameters as an array, `p`.

When you add to the queue you would do something like `queue.push ([f, arguments])` and when the time comes to make that call it would be something like `queue[0][0].apply (null, queue[0][1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can queue up an ad-hoc function that contains your API call with the argument already bound:

```
var that = this;
this.function_queue.push(function() {
    that.make_api_call(data);
));
```

The aliasing of `this` to `that` is required, because inside the anonymous function, `this` would not be bound to the same object as outside.

Note this technique is similar to eclanrs' answer, but doesn't rely on `bind` method's availability.

Comment: I dont see how this would keep the parameters