# bind a function to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I have a function in javascript

```
function foo(callback) {
    console.log("Hello");
    callback();
}
```

and another function

```
function bar() {
  console.log("world");
}
```

and I want to make a function `FooBar`

```
FooBar = foo.bind(this, bar);
```

This works fine, however what I'm actually trying to do is create a [function queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130520/writing-a-function-queue-in-javascript/17130540#17130540), and often I will have to bind a none function parameter before binding a callback, as in the following example

```
function foo() {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    var func = arguments[1];
    func();
}

function bar() {
    console.log("world");
}

foo.bind(this, "hello");
var FooBar = foo.bind(this, bar);

FooBar();
```

which produces this error

```
[Function: bar]

TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can a I bind a function to another function once it has been bound to other none function types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're binding `"Hello"` to `foo`, and then separately binding `bar` to `foo` as well - shouldn't you bind `bar` to the result of the first `bind`, like this:

```
var FooHello = foo.bind(this, "hello");
var FooBar = FooHello.bind(this, bar);
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/XM4kQ/) (which logs "Hello", "world").

Comment: For a less convoluted example see http://jsfiddle.net/XM4kQ/8/. and read up on bind here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind as the example this fiddle links to makes it look like you are actually binding bar to a bind of foo...

Answer (score 4):

The bind method doesn't bind functions to one another, it's purpose is to fix the context of the 'this' keyword and any arguments when the function is called. It then returns a new function, leaving the original unchanged.

So: `foo.bind(this, "hello")`actually has no effect. Calling bind the second time creates a new function with a fixed argument of `bar`. The reason you get an error is because with only one argument passed, `arguments[1]` is undefined.

You could do as Richie suggests and add an intermediate variable, or just pass both arguments in a single bind:

```
var FooBar = foo.bind(this, "hello", bar);
```

It is probably a good idea to also include run time checking so your function can detect when it is dealing with a function. This will save you having to worry about argument order.

```
if(typeof func === 'function'){
  func();
}
```